# Plot and Table in the same line

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, parametric-functions, boundary-conditions

I would like to plot this with different y1 but isn't working!!

```
Clear["Global`*"]
sol = FullSimplify[DSolve[{Derivative[1][y][x] + (3/2)*(a - b)*(y[x]/x) - ((3/2)*a - 1)*(1/(y[x]*x^3)) == 0, y[1] == y1}, y[x], x]]

Plot[{y[x]/.Table[ sol , {y1, 0, 10}]} /. {y1, a -> 13/10, b -> 7/10}, {x, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: `Plot[Evaluate[
  y[x] /. sol /. {y1 -> #, a -> 13/10, b -> 7/10} & /@ Range[10]], {x,
   1, 10}]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Plot` and `Table` in the following way:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[y[x] /. sol, {y1, 0, 10}]] /. {a -> 13/10, 
   b -> 7/10}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]